# android get request exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.

Tags: android, get, request

android get request exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=http://stage1-go.university:80/user/profile{"userId":"0"}"

Hi, I tried to make the Get request, code here:

```
public InputStream setGetRequest(String concreteUrl, String jsonAsString) throws IOException {
        String url = protocol + siteUrl + ":" + httpPort + "/" +  concreteUrl + jsonAsString;
        url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        httpGet.setHeader("sessid", ClientAPI.getSessionId());

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String getServerString = client.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
        return null;
    }
```

and here my logs:

```
12-11 17:59:50.731    2715-2733/com.podorojnik E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-312
    Process: com.podorojnik, PID: 2715
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=http://stage1-go.university:80/user/profile{"userId":"0"}
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
            at com.zeoalliance.internship.pilotproject.server.NetworkRequest.setGetRequest(NetworkRequest.java:100)
            at com.zeoalliance.internship.pilotproject.server.NetworkRequest.getInputStream(NetworkRequest.java:60)
            at com.zeoalliance.internship.pilotproject.server.NetworkRequest.execute(NetworkRequest.java:45)
            at com.zeoalliance.internship.pilotproject.server.ClientAPI.getUserProfile(ClientAPI.java:156)
            at com.zeoalliance.internship.pilotproject.activities.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:58)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I also added a special permissions in the manifest and it didn't help me

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Can somebody help with this?

Comment: why are you passing this:
http://stage1-go.university:80/user/profile{"userId":"0"}
?

Comment: He means: why are you adding `{"userId":"0"}` to your url. Thats invalid.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning directly null value;

In your setGetRequest method put below code:

```
String getServerString = client.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
        return getServerString ;
```

instead of:

```
String getServerString = client.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
        return null;
```

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

you have your path set as:

```
path=http://stage1-go.university:80/
```

stage1-go.university is not a host or even a valid URL.  A top level domain like .com, .net or something like that is needed.  If this would work you should be able to go to http://stage1-go.university in any browser, but that won't work - I just tried it